# When I am trying to poll the same Amazon SQS from two different terminal tabs, I am not getting same message in both of them

Tags: amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, long-polling

I have created an Amazon SNS topic. I have one Amazon SQS queue subscribed to the topic.

I have created a default SQS queue (not a FIFO queue).

I am using `sqs-consumer` API for long polling the `SQS` queue.

```
const app = Consumer.create({
    queueUrl: 'https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx',
    handleMessage: async (message) => {

        console.log(message);
    },
    sqs: sqs//new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'})
});

app.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err.message);
});

app.on('processing_error', (err) => {
    console.error(err.message);
});

app.on('timeout_error', (err) => {
    console.error(err.message);
});

app.start();
```

When I am running this piece of `js` file from a single terminal by doing `node sqs_client.js` , then everything is working perfectly fine and messages are coming in proper order.

But, if open another terminal window and run `node sqs_client.js` , then the orders of incoming messages become very random. Newer messages may come in the first terminal window or second terminal window in any order.

Why is it happening so? And is there any way to prevent this so that I can get the same message in both the terminal windows at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ask: "Is there any way...that I can get the **same message in both the terminal windows at the same time**."

This is not the way Amazon SQS operates. The general flow of Amazon SQS is:

- Messages are sent to the queue
- The messages sit in the queue for up to 14 days (can be extended)
- A consumer calls `ReceiveMessages()`, asking for up to 10 messages at a time
- When a message is received, it is marked as *invisible*
- When a consumer has finished processing the message, the consumer calls `DeleteMessage()` to remove the message from the queue
- If the consumer does *not* call `DeleteMessage()` within the **invisibility timeout period**, the message will *reappear* on the queue and will be available for a consumer to receive

Thus, messages are intentionally only available to one consumer at a time. Once a message is grabbed, it is specifically not available for other consumers to receive.

If your requirement is for two consumers to receive the same message, then you will need to redesign your architecture. You do not provide enough details to recommend a particular approach, but options include using multiple Amazon SQS queues or sending messages directly via Amazon SNS rather than Amazon SQS.

Comment: hi  @John Rotenstein, you have perfectly understood my problem. Kudos for that :-). Coming to my architecture, in my backend server's code , I am publishing message to SNS topic . And the SNS topic has this queue as endpoint.  And in my front end code , I am long polling the queue . Is there any other way , in which I can get multiple consumers get the same message at the same time ?

Comment: The only way to do this using Amazon SQS is to have Amazon SNS send the message to **two Amazon SQS queues**. Each consumer would then read from its own queue. However, there are no guarantees that each would get the same message at the same time. Or, Amazon SNS can send a message to an **HTTP endpoint**, so it can _trigger_ your program, rather than your program polling a queue. It can send to multiple endpoints at the same time. This is a "push" architecture, rather than a "pull/poll" architecture.

Comment: Hi @John Rotenstein : You are bang on target. Thanks a lot.

 If you do feel that my question has some meaningful values (rather than mindless copy-pasting from existing questions), please feel free to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The SQS product page at: https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/

**Q: Does Amazon SQS provide message ordering?**

> Yes. FIFO (first-in-first-out) queues preserve the exact order in
>   which messages are sent and received. If you use a FIFO queue, you
>   don't have to place sequencing information in your messages. For more
>   information, see FIFO Queue Logic in the Amazon SQS Developer Guide.
>
> Standard queues provide a loose-FIFO capability that attempts to
>   preserve the order of messages. However, because standard queues are
>   designed to be massively scalable using a highly distributed
>   architecture, receiving messages in the exact order they are sent is
>   not guaranteed.

Are you perhaps using the standard queue and thus loose-FIFO?

Comment: I am not using FIFO queue . But , I feel problem lies with my understanding of SQS in general , not with FIFO architecture.